# Как остановить условие if в Cи если ответ положительный(if продолжается , хотя я дал правильный ответ) ? Что то вроде break

Tags: c, if, break

**Вот задача:**
*Угадать число, которое загадал пользователь, используя только инструкцию if-else.*
Число должно быть в диапазоне от 0 до 10ти.
**Вот код:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    printf("Да это 1 , нет это 0\nЭто число 6 ?\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (a == 1)
        printf("Ваше число 6\n");
    else
        printf("Это число 1 ?\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        if (a == 1)
            printf("Ваше число 1\n");
            return 0;
        else
            printf("Это число 10 ?\n");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            if (a == 1)
                printf("Ваше число 10\n");
            else
                printf("Это число 2?\n");
                scanf("%d", &a);
                if (a == 1)
                    printf("Ваше число 2\n");
                else
                    printf("Это число 3 ?\n");
                    scanf("%d", &a);
                    if (a == 1)
                        printf("Ваше число 3\n");
                    else
                        printf("Это число 4?\n");
                        scanf("%d", &a);
                        if (a == 1)
                            printf("Ваше число 4\n");
    return 0;                       
}
```

Comment: А фигурные скобки разрешается использовать?

Comment: заведите массив вопросов и цикл

Comment: Я рекомендую ознакомиться с синтаксисом языка для начала. В частности про фигурные скобки.

Comment: Нужно использовать только оператор if. Да, скобки можно. Час уже мучаюсь

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{

    int a;

    printf_s("Да это 1 , нет это 0\nЭто число 6 ?\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    if (a == 1)
        printf("Ваше число 6\n");
    else
    {
        printf("Это число 1 ?\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &a);
        if (a == 1)
            printf("Ваше число 1\n");
        else
        {
            printf("Это число 10 ?\n");
            scanf_s("%d", &a);
            if (a == 1)
                printf("Ваше число 10\n");
            else
            {
                printf("Это число 2?\n");
                scanf_s("%d", &a);
                if (a == 1)
                    printf("Ваше число 2\n");
                else
                {
                    printf("Это число 3 ?\n");
                    scanf_s("%d", &a);
                    if (a == 1)
                        printf("Ваше число 3\n");
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Это число 4?\n");
                        scanf_s("%d", &a);
                        if (a == 1)
                            printf("Ваше число 4\n");
                        else
                            printf("Дописать для 5,7,8 если я верно понял задачу, угадайка методом перебора это конечно что то новое");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```